# Where is the cache of DataContractSerializer?

Tags: .net, performance, wcf

When I use DataContractSerializer to serialize a big instance, it will cost many times. However, if this serialization happen second time, it will become really really fast. It seems there are some kind of "cache" exist in the memory. My test code like below:

```
//Create a big instance
object instance = ObjectInitializer.CreateObjectWithValue(type);
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(type);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

Stopwatch watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser.WriteObject(ms, instance);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);

ser = new DataContractSerializer(type);
watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser.WriteObject(ms, instance);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);
```

Program Output:

```
8605177
36970
```

Anyone know where could I find that "cache", so I could use this cache to improve the first seralization time.

**Update:**
After see @Daniel Hilgarth's answer, I do another tests. He is right about the warm system, but from my test result, it seems it really exist some "cache".

I choose two different type of instances:
First test:

```
watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser1.WriteObject(ms, instance1);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);

watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser2.WriteObject(ms, instance2);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);
```

Second test swithch two instance's sequence:

```
watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser2.WriteObject(ms, instance2);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);

watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ser1.WriteObject(ms, instance1);
watcher.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watcher.ElapsedTicks);
```

Results:
1st:

```
8630129
10796746
```

2nd:

```
14346583
7543526
```

From the result, we could find warm system really run fast then the cold system. But the second time is still very long, compare to seralizing two instances in the same type twice.

Comment: How do you intend to "use this cache to improve the first seralization (sic) time"? Caching can only EVER improve the performance of subsequent runs. However, it can be noted that `DataContractSerializer` was never designed for performance, but for compatibility. Consider another Serializer if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a common mistake here. You are comparing a cold system - the first serialization - to a warm system - the second serialization.

Try serializing two *different* instances and you will see that the second serialization is still faster.

In other words: There is no cache.

Also, please make sure to read Eric Lippert's series about [Benchmarking mistakes](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/).

Comment: You are correct about the warm system, I did another test and from the test it seems the "cache" really exist. Could have a look about the update in the questions? thanks.